# Command Prompt Shortcut .lnk That Runs Program

Tags: windows, command-line, shortcuts, command-line-arguments

You can set up command prompt shortcuts so that the window has specified colors, sizes, and locations on the screen.  I have many of these set up for many different programs that I like to see all at once on my screen. I have a batch file full of commands like this:

```
START C:\Things\Prompt-Window-1.lnk
```

The problem is that the .lnk only opens the window.  I see no way to make it actually launch a program either in the batch file or the link properties.  I have to enter those commands manually in each window. I see how to do this just by letting Windows open a command window, but is there a way to do this with my links to the color coded/sized/positions windows?

Answer (score 1):

The syntax for the `START` command is:

```
START <title> <program>
```

plus a few extra options. ([Reference](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/start))

So you're basically just setting the *title* for a new *Command Prompt* window to be `C:\Things\Prompt-Window-1.lnk`.

If you want the actual *program* to open, change each line in your batch file to:

```
START "" C:\Things\Prompt-Window-1.lnk
```

Comment: I've tried all the combinations of this syntax, but it does not run a program in the command window when it opens.  The window seems to get it's title from the name of the shortcut.